# Please investigate for the reason of no confirmation. Over 2 day zero confirmation. Fee Paid. Please help!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Can any miner help confirm my BTC transaction!  Zero confirmation for over 1.5 days now.  Feed was included. Please investigate to find out the reason of this delay, any mistake from the sender or receiver wallet that need to taken care off?  Please help.  Below is the link to the blockchain.

https://blockchain.info/tx/3f4ca76ec5d39f700a6284e1282bfbb77c8be474f810191840d9441fd8e97d81

Comment: Your fee rate was just shy of 60 satoshi per byte, however we haven't been below that since this weekend and have now reached 400 sat/B

Answer (score 0):

Your fee is 58.928 sat/Byte. Looking at the current backlog and https://bitcoinfees.21.co/ this might take a while. What wallet did you use to send it? You can try your luck using https://www.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/